# Run Linux executable on Raspbian Jessie 4.4

Tags: raspbian, linux, noobs

I try to install the linux headers by:

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

But the file still has no recognizable format.

Comment: Running that command should set if off installing... is there a specific error message you are getting?

Comment: Well, it says that failed resolving "archive.raspberrypi.org" and I try to execute sudo apt-get update but failed to fetch some http's

Comment: @CarolinaVictoria Could you edit the question and cut&paste the command you run and the response.  I do not understand what you are doing.

Comment: The pi isn't on the network then.. you must be connected to the internet for apt-get to work.

Answer (score 1):

### Your Raspberry Pi is not connected to the Internet

Do you know if your Raspberry Pi is connected to the Internet?

---

If your Raspberry Pi is connected to the Internet, the `ping -c 4 raspberrypi.org` command will look like this:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ ping -c 4 raspberrypi.org
PING raspberrypi.org (93.93.130.214) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.93.130.214: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=153 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.130.214: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=165 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.130.214: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=155 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.130.214: icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=153 ms

--- raspberrypi.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 153.781/157.298/165.971/5.081 ms
pi@raspberry:~ $
```

---

If your Raspberry Pi is **not** connected to the Internet, the `ping -c 4 raspberrypi.org` command will look like this:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ ping -c 4 raspberrypi.org
ping: unknown host raspberrypi.org
pi@raspberry:~ $
```

---

You must plug your Raspberry Pi into your Internet Router using an Ethernet cable to connect your Raspberry Pi to the Internet.

Or, if you have Wifi on your Raspberry Pi, you must connect your Raspberry Pi to your Internet Router using Wifi.

Please go here for instructions for Wifi: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/